# How to disable mousewheel

Tags: javascript

I need to disable mousewheel in some event, my code works in FF and Chrome but it doesn't work in IE (7,8,9)

```
$("div").mouseout(function() { 
    document.onmousewheel = null;
    if(window.addEventListener){
        document.removeEventListener('mousewheel', scroll, false);
        document.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scroll, false);
    }
});
```

(doesn't work in IE but i read 1 article where was written that `document.onmousewheel = null;` works for IE)
thank you

Comment: From what I understand of your question, you want to make the mouse wheel *not* scroll, but from your code, it looks like you're just removing your listeners. I think what you'd need to do is have a listener that calls `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I am not sure now., my code works like this: if user hover 1 div I allow mousewheel event , and if user mouseout from div I want disable mousewheel event

Comment: Maybe use two separate listeners. One to disable default behavior, and the other to do whatever you wanted to do otherwise. When the user hovers in/out, just swap out the listeners so that only one of them is active at a time.

Comment: Isn't it more easier if I only add/remove same listeners? edit:  I find to use detachEvent(), now it works for IE(7,8,9) but it doesn't work for FF and chrome .. I really don't know why

Comment: I edit my post.. now it doesn't work in FF and Chrome, this is very interesting, if detachEvent was before removeEventListener() it doesn't work, but if is it after removeEventListener() it finally works, edit: problem solved. thanks

Comment: I am confused after all of these edits to your comment :P but I see "problem solved" so yay.

Comment: Be a good fellow and answer your own post and accept the answer, so that others can benefit by the assistance you received here? It will also improve your rep and answer rate if you accept an answer.